# Adding a panel to a theme region

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Below is my theme layout :

[image]

What I would like to do is to use the panels module to add
a 4 column block at the region labeled 'content'.  I have
already tried adding a node to the content region and creating
a variant using the panels module for the particular node.
But this didn't work.  I tried switching the selection rules
from "Node:Type" to "Front-page" but still no luck with this.

Suggestions appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of the panels module.  Panels makes panel pages, in which you place panes in whatever arrangement you want.  The panel needs a url to control, and that url can have variables in it like Node ID.

So, here is a walk through of how to use the panels in the way I think you want from the selection rules you mention:
The panel should have a path assigned, like "welcome" or "welcome/%nid"
If you have used the %nid path, set up the context to use that argument for the node id.

You only need a selection rule if you have more than one variant, as that is how the panel selects which one to use.  Example, selection rule on variantA says use it when %nid validates to a node of node:typeA.  Selection rule on variantB ... etc.

In the content section of you panel control, upper left point, is a button or link that says "show layout designer", click that.  http://expressmagazine.net/sites/default/files/imagesArticle/panels_drupal_8.png
That will let you change how many rows and columns and regions you have on the panel.  If I recall correctly a row can hold columns or regions, a column can hold rows, and content in the same region gets stacked vertically.

Since panels layouts are inside the "content" of a page, the 3-segment header and 4-segment footer of your theme will stay.  You will probably want two rows, one of which with the 4 regions to make the columns in your question, and one of which with a single region to hold the full-width content.  If you have the %nid setup, you can use pieces of the node (specific fields) in the regions.

Then in your site information page set "welcome" as your homepage.